# How to move all files to subdirectories by extension name in the specified DIR directory?

Tags: linux, bash

How to move all files (except directories) to subdirectories by extension name in the specified DIR directory?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, [globbing](https://linuxhint.com/bash_globbing_tutorial/) should help you. If you're going to be using linux for a while, I'd recommend reading up on it, as it makes using linux and bash much easier.

To directly answer your question, something like this should work:

```
mv *.<extension> <target directory>
```